# Open URL from drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, drop-down-menu

On my site I have a drop down list & each option has its URL. When you select one of the options and click the button, the corresponding URL opens in the same tab.

**PROBLEM:**
My form works, BUT I need to have **2 separate forms** on the same page. Right now, only the first form is working. So if I click the button on the second form, it will bring results from the firm form. e.g. I have "Option A" selected on the first form, and "Option C" on the second. I click 'submit' on the second form but it opens a URL from "Option A" of the first form.

You can change my current code/script completely as long as both drop-downs work individually on the same page.

Here is the code:

HTML

```
<form class="spec-table" name="dropdown">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="This is my drop down" />
      This is my drop down
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="selected" id="target" accesskey="E" class="spec-field1">
        <option selected value="URL-1">Option A</option>
        <option value="URL-2">Option B</option>
        <option value="URL-3">Option C</option>
        <option value="URL-4">Option D</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <input type="button" class="button-spec" value="Visit Link!"
         onclick="goToNewPage(document.dropdown.selected)">
</form>
```

Javascript

```
function goToNewPage() {
  if(document.getElementById('target').value) {
    window.location.href = document.getElementById('target').value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't have same id assigned to multiple elements.. id's should be unique.. so you should create two selects with different ids and change your goToNewPage function to something like this

```
function goToNewPage(i) {
                if(document.getElementById('target' + i).value){
                    window.location.href = document.getElementById('target' + i).value;
                }
            }
```

just an example..

```
<form>
  <select  id="target1" accesskey="E" >
    <option selected value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
                <option value="URL-2">Option B</option>
                <option value="URL-3">Option C</option>
                <option value="URL-4">Option D</option>
                </select>
       <input type="button"  value="Visit Link!"
 onclick="goToNewPage(1)">
  </form>
  <br>

  <form>
    <select  id="target2" accesskey="R" >
      <option selected value="http://www.bing.com">Bing</option>
                <option value="URL-2">Option B</option>
                <option value="URL-3">Option C</option>
                <option value="URL-4">Option D</option>
                </select>
         <input type="button"  value="Visit Link!"
 onclick="goToNewPage(2)">
  </form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Your version is working on fiddle, but when I implement the exact same code on my site (and update JS), the buttons won't work once clicked on. On fiddle I use "No wrap - in <head>" Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/vladmedv/d5Hwn/

Comment: @user2875670 in your jsfiddle.. 404 that's an server error.. :/

Comment: @user2875670 .. and about your site.. i chose custom, fast,custom,fas,t custom and got all four products .. is that what it's supposed to do??

Comment: basically there are two tabs on the page 'custom' & 'fast' each tab has its own drop-down of products. BUT you can see here (more clear) http://goo.gl/zgSEBk

Comment: @user2875670 my code was just an example.. you just need to add your urls to your option value...  and i saw your site.. tried both custom and fast tab.. two times each... it seems it working fine.. is this is what it's supposed to do??  http://snag.gy/4eLCy.jpg

Comment: Now I see it works for me too, but only in Firefox. On Chrome the buttons aren't clickable. Do you know why that could be?

Comment: i'm not a big fan of chrome... but i'll check what's the chrome problem in your site... gimme five minutes.....

Comment: it runs fine on chrome too.. the buttons are clickable... i don't see a problem.. http://snag.gy/ILthc.jpg

Comment: That's so weird, on my Chrome console it gives an error: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
goToNewPage
onclick

Comment: Anyway, if it works on your end then 90% is solved. Thank you so much buddy, you really helped me a lot today! So many good people here, I'll also try to contribute with whatever knowledge I have =)

Comment: Btw, now it worked! I removed the old JS file and created a new one. Thanks again buddy =)

Comment: no problem dude.. im happy i could be of help..  and by the way.. you might want to fix the below issuse of 404 .. http://snag.gy/069oA.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the code is identifying the `select` element using an ID. When you create multiple instances of this form on the same page, and load an element using `getElementById`, you get the first instance of the `select` element.

A fix will be to use `class` names to identify the `select` element.

This should work for you:

```
<form class="spec-table" name="dropdown">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="This is my drop down" />This is my drop down</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="selected" class="target" accesskey="E" class="spec-field1">
                <option selected value="URL-1">Option A</option>
                <option value="URL-2">Option B</option>
                <option value="URL-3">Option C</option>
                <option value="URL-4">Option D</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <input type="button" class="button-spec" value="Visit Link!"/>
</form>

<form class="spec-table" name="dropdown">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="This is my drop down" />This is my drop down</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="selected" class="target" accesskey="E" class="spec-field1">
                <option selected value="URL-5">OptionE</option>
                <option value="URL-6">Option F</option>
                <option value="URL-7">Option G</option>
                <option value="URL-8">Option H</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <input type="button" class="button-spec" value="Visit Link!"/>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(".target").change(function(){
    console.log(this.value);
});
```

Of course, you will have to change that callback method to do whatever action you want to be taken.